# How can I draw same images along a path using cocos2D iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I trying to draw same images along a straight path.

I already know where the path begins and ends.

How can I make it?

Please Help.

Always thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please Explain the condition,So that i can understand the way you want draw images...

As I understand your problem you want to draw series of same image along with a path, in that case you can use [CCRibbon](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14138).

Comment: Actually I making a kind of hand drawing application. I have a picture what I want to place along with touch moving. I read your answer and trying CCRibbon, but it's not what I want. It make images along with the line but there are gaps between two images. I want to reduce that. Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful. If you have any solution for this, PLS let me know. Bless You!